# Can't Get 'tag' Page To Display only Tagged Posts

Tags: tags

I made a tag.php under my theme folder in order to style all of the tagged post pages from urls like 'www.mywebsite.com/tag/kittens'.

However, if I go to 'www.mywebsite.com/tag/kittens' it displays all of my posts, even the ones that are not tagged 'kittens' or at all. I used the the standard loop, and I can't find a way to alter it to grab the tag page name and only return those posts without making a separate 'tag-kittens.php' type page for every single tag.

Help?

---

```
<?php
    get_header();
    query_posts( 'posts_per_page=5' ); ?>

<?php the_tags( $before, $sep, $after ); ?>

 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

 <div class="post">

 <!-- Display the Title as a link to the Post's permalink. -->
 <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

 <!-- Display the date (November 16th, 2009 format) and a link to other posts by this posts author. -->
 <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></small>

  <div class="entry">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </div>

 </div> <!-- closes the first div box -->

 <?php endwhile; else: ?>
 <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
 <?php endif;
    get_footer();
 ?>
```

Comment: Hard to help without seeing the template. Please add the code needed to reproduce the behavior. And welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange!

Comment: I am literally just using the standard loop.

Comment: No, you don’t. You are using `query_posts()`, overwriting the main query. Remove that, and your template will work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
query_posts( 'posts_per_page=5' );
```

You're overwriting the query for this page with a query for the 5 latest posts, regardless of tag, category, etc.. If you remove that line, your template will work as expected.

If you want to limit tag pages to only 5 posts, use a `pre_get_posts` action:

```
function wpa69774_limit_tags( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_tag() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa69774_limit_tags' );
```