# Tag Page Not Listing All Posts With Tag

Tags: theme-development, tags

I am using tag.php to display content when a user visits a tag page. Everything I need is working great, however it is only showing the most recent 6 posts that have the tag. I need it to list all posts with the tag.

When I change the "Blog pages show at most" under Reading to a large number, it breaks part of my site so I would like to do it in the tag.php code.

I know you can list all posts by using the 'posts_per_page' => -1 parameter, but am having trouble implementing that into my code.

This is in my tag.php file

```
<?php 

        if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php $term_id = get_queried_object_id(); ?>
            <div class="pantry-thumbnail"><?php the_term_thumbnail( $term_id, $size = 'post-thumbnail', $attr = '' ) ?></div>


            <?php
                // Show an optional term description.
                $term_description = term_description();
                if ( ! empty( $term_description ) ) :
                    printf( '<div class="taxonomy-description">%s</div>', $term_description );
                endif;
            ?>

            <strong>Recipes</strong>


            <?php
                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            ?>

            <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </li>
            </ul>


            <?
                endwhile;

                else :
                    // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
                    get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

                endif;

                wp_reset_query();
            ?>
```

Thank  you for any help!

Comment: You might want to try a custom WP_Query since the default loop is only going to pull in a max of "blog pages show at most".

Comment: I have tried creating a custom query, and all I was able to accomplish was listing all posts, not posts related to the tag. Would you mind helping me with doing that specifically in this code?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this issue by adding this to the functions.php file

```
function wpa69774_limit_tags( $query ) {
 if ( $query->is_tag() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
 }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa69774_limit_tags' );
```

after finally stumbling upon this question: [Can't Get 'tag' Page To Display only Tagged Posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69774/cant-get-tag-page-to-display-only-tagged-posts)